# Pandas: Creating NaNs when checking membership of one column in another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this (it's thousands of rows in actuality):

```
           A    B
0   [C, D, E]   C
1   [H, I, J]   Z
```

Can recreate it with:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({"A":[["C", "D", "E"], ["H", "I", "J"]], "B":["C", "Z"]})
```

I want to record a 1 in a new column, `C`, if that row's `B` value is contained in that row's `A` column.  For example, "C" is contained in row 0's `A` column, so it gets a 1.  On the other hand, "Z" is not contained in row 1's `A` column, so it gets a 0.

Here was my attempt.  Note that before doing this, there are no `NaN`s in either column `A` or `B`.

```
df["C"] = pd.Series([b in a for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]).astype(int)
```

However, this puts about 2,000 `NaN`s into column `C`.  I took off the `.astype(int)` portion, and have the same number of `NaN`s, so think that part is fine.

Any idea what might be creating these `NaN`s?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a test case where NaNs are generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what would happen if your dataframe doesn't have the natural index (numbers going up from 0 to the length of the frame-1), because the assignment will try to align on shared indices.  For example:

```
In [111]: df
Out[111]: 
           A  B
0  [C, D, E]  C
1  [H, I, J]  Z

In [112]: df.index = [0, 2]

In [113]: df
Out[113]: 
           A  B
0  [C, D, E]  C
2  [H, I, J]  Z

In [114]: df["C"] = pd.Series([10, 20])  # has index [0, 1]

In [115]: df
Out[115]: 
           A  B     C
0  [C, D, E]  C  10.0
2  [H, I, J]  Z   NaN
```

whereas if we use a matching index, it'll work:

```
In [116]: df["C"] = pd.Series([10, 20], index=[0, 2])

In [117]: df
Out[117]: 
           A  B   C
0  [C, D, E]  C  10
2  [H, I, J]  Z  20
```

There are lots of ways to get the alignment to work, whether by explicitly creating something with the right index, by not having one at all, or by getting pandas to build one on the way:

```
In [118]: df["D"] = pd.Series([11, 22], index=df.index)

In [119]: df["E"] = [11, 22]

In [120]: df["F"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["D"] * 5, axis=1)

In [121]: df
Out[121]: 
           A  B   C   D   E    F
0  [C, D, E]  C  10  11  11   55
2  [H, I, J]  Z  20  22  22  110
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) should do the trick:

```
temp['C'] = temp.apply(lambda x: x['B'] in x['A'], axis=1).astype(int)
```